# Greenplum ERROR : relation sequence_tablename does not exist

Tags: c#, postgresql, odbc, greenplum

Executing a Query from C# code to PostgreSQL

```
INSERT INTO SCHEMA_NAME.Table_name(c1) values (nextval(\'sequence_name\'));
```

Working If I manually add any int value in the place of nextval() & also query working if I run on DB directly

Comment: Like the error says, you do not have a sequence created for the table.

Answer (score 0):

Like your error says, you do not have a sequence created for this table.

Something in this direction would probably work...

`CREATE SEQUENCE sequence_tablename INCREMENT 1 START 1;`

Comment: Sequence is created already & when I run the same query in DBVisualizer it successfully runs. But not working through c# code

Comment: Did you remember to annotate your unique key in your model? 

It might help if you could provide some more info about how your C# code actually looks.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add schema name before nextval()
like nextval(schema_name."sequence_name")